# why cant choose "manually select region" in postman desktop?

Tags: proxy, postman

I just want to send requests from US cuz API work only in this country. So i go monitor collection in postman and try to choose this region but radio-button just unclickable?

Please help me!

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/ZqdELTK.png here a screen. I just cant click here!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The free plan (I'm assuming that's what you're using) doesn't allow you to manually select a region - If you hover over the option you should see a tooltip stating this:

[image: Monitor Plan]